# Overflow:hidden pushes content right

Tags: html, css

I'm making a small website.

The problem is:

I have an article tag with a set height and width:

```
.main-content-wrapper article { color: white; margin: auto; overflow: hidden; }
.main-content-wrapper article { width: 980px; height: 457px; font-size: 20px; }
```

In firefox and safari, when `overflow: hidden` is set, the entire article is pushed to the right.

With `overflow: hidden`: 
[image: overflow:hidden]

Without `overflow: hidden`:
[image]

Anyone knows why? In chrome, ie10 and opera its just fine.

Link: *link removed*

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle example

Comment: Give fixed width to the child elements.

Comment: @btevfik I tried, but I can't recreate it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take a look at your markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="content-menu-wrapper">
        <nav id="content-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./article.html">HVA ER OUTPUT?</a></li>
                <li><a href="./article.html">HVOR ER OUTPUT?</a></li>
                <li><a href="./article.html">NÅR ER OUTPUT?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav> <!-- end content-menu -->
    </div> <!-- end content-menu-wrapper -->
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="main-content-wrapper">
        <article>
            <p>I love pudding jelly bear claw I love cookie 
               croissant pie.......</p>
        </article>
    </div> <!-- main-content-wrapper -->
</div>
```

In the first row, you have your `content-menu`, which has floated elements (`<li>`), which causes the width of the row to collapse.  As a result, the following element with content (`<article>`), flows to the right of the menu.

You can fix this by adding the following rule to your CSS:

```
.content-menu-wrapper {
    background: url("../images/menu_background.png") repeat-x scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    overflow: auto:
}
```

The `overflow: auto` will take care of the collapsed width and your layout will work.

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/NEJKj/

**Cross-Browser Comment**
Firefox seems to handle floats slightly differently from Chrome, IE, Safari/windows, Opera.  Someone else may have some insight about this.

Comment: Your very welcome, glad to help!  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
float:left;  /* if you want to float this to left side */
margin: 0px auto; /* if you want to center it horizontaly */
```

sorry for question
but why are you using 2 lines with the same selector? :)

Comment: That's not working.

I'm using two because in my css I'm using media queries, the top selector is general and the bottom selector is specific to a media query.

Comment: The problem originates from the preceding element (`div.row`), related to floated content that is collapsing the width and affecting the right margin.